# Как написать for_each parallel для std::map?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, stl

мне необходимо многопоточно обработать элементы std::map.
c++ 17 для это есть for_each parallel, но я работаю на C++ 14.
я написал такую функцию но он работает только с Forward итераторами.

```
template <typename It, typename Fn>
void parallel_for_each(It begin, It end, Fn&& function)
{
    const auto diff = std::distance(begin, end);
    constexpr auto num_threads = 8;
    std::vector<std::future<void>> fts;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
    {
        auto l = [&function](auto b, const auto thread_id, const auto n 
                        , const auto d)
    {
        std::for_each(b + (thread_id * d / n)
                        , b + ((thread_id + 1) * d / n), function);
    };
    fts.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, l, begin, i, num_threads 
                        , diff));
    }
    for (auto& f : fts)
    {
        f.get();
    }
}
```

Прошу предложить оптимальное решение.

Comment: наверное тут подразумевается только с random access итераторами? Что мешает сделать вектор из этих итераторов или использовать интрузивные контейнеры?

Comment: да если скопировать все значения в std::vector всё срабатывает но тут необходимо чтобы все работало максимально эффектив и не хочется тратить лишние ресурсы на копирование.

Comment: я нигде не предлагал копировать значения в вектор...

Comment: @Argishty Ayvazyan,   Ради чего вы не хотите поменять компилятор?...

Comment: не я выбираю компилятор компании :)